# Mongo 2.4 Text Command/ full text search using mongo-ruby-driver

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I want to perform full text search on my collection. Since i am using mongo 2.4 I would like to do it with mongodb's [text command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/text/#dbcmd.text)

The way to do it in mongo's console is (as per mongo's official docs.)

```
db.collection.runCommand( "text", { search: <string> })
```

It returns expected results.

Now, I want to achieve same in ruby/rails. I am using `mongo gem version 1.8.4`

As per their [change log/history](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/wiki/History)
there is a support for new MongoDB 2.4 index types

But how can i run the `text command` on a collection with ruby.

I went through this [blog post](http://kylebanker.com/blog/2010/03/28/does-the-driver-support-feature-x/). But it did'nt help

**Update:**

I tried,

```
  command = BSON::OrderedHash.new
  command['find'] = collection
  command['text'] = {'search' => 'string'}
  result = @db.command(command)
```

But it gives

```
Database command 'find' failed: (ok: '0.0'; errmsg: 'no such cmd: find'; bad cmd: '{"find"=>"project", "text"=>{"search"=>"string"}}').
```

**Update 2:**

Similar exists for [php](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/mongodb-user/full%2420text%2420search%2420mongo/mongodb-user/59mNpQGa0xc/oHbsADcwd2sJ). I am looking ruby's equivalent for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to use BSON::OrderedHash with Ruby 1.8. If you're running Ruby 1.9 or greater you can use the following syntax to create/query on a text index.

```
require 'mongo'
include Mongo

client = MongoClient.new
db = client['my_database']
coll = db['my_collection']

# create a text index
coll.ensure_index({:field_name => Mongo::TEXT})

# run a text query
db.command({:text => 'my_collection', :search => 'search string'})
db.command({:text => 'my_collection', :search => 'search string', :filter => {:foo => 'bar'}})
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no working mongodb installation here, but the following should do the trick:

```
command = OrderedHash.new
command['text'] = <collectionname>
command['search'] = <string>
result = @db.command(command)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this before. Dint work. how does it know what collection to search on. the command() is on db object.

Comment: That dint work. `undefined method 'command' for #<Mongo::Collection:0xa181910>`

Comment: @Mashit sorry I messed things up; finally I updated an answer with the code that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I used,

```
  command = {}
  command["text"] = collection_name
  command["search"] = "search_string"
  result = @db.command(command)
```

looks like it works.
I will wait for other answers though.